# Converting multiple rows into one row by ID

Tags: sql, sql-server, database

What I am trying to achieve is group them by `id` and create a column for the `date` as well as `data`.

The background of the dataset are it is lab result taken by participant and some test are not able to be taken on same day due to fasting restrictions n etc. The database I am using is SQL Server.

Below are my DataSet as well as the desired output.

Sample dataset:

```
create table Sample 
(
      Id int,
      LAB_DATE date,
      A_CRE_1 varchar(100),
      B_GLUH_1 varchar(100),
      C_LDL_1 varchar(100),
      D_TG_1 varchar(100),
      E_CHOL_1 varchar(100),
      F_HDL_1 varchar(100),
      G_CRPH_1 varchar(100),
      H_HBA1C_1 varchar(100),
      I_GLU120_1 varchar(100),
      J_GLUF_1 varchar(100),
      K_HCR_1 varchar(100)
)

insert into Sample(Id, LAB_DATE,A_CRE_1, B_GLUH_1,C_LDL_1,E_CHOL_1,F_HDL_1,H_HBA1C_1,K_HCR_1)
values (01, '2017-11-21', '74', '6.4', '2.04', '4.17', '1.64', '6.1', '2.54')

insert into sample (Id, LAB_DATE, I_GLU120_1) 
values (01, '2017-11-22','8.8')

insert into sample (Id, LAB_DATE, D_TG_1) 
values (01, '2017-11-23','0.56')

insert into sample (Id,LAB_DATE,A_CRE_1,B_GLUH_1,C_LDL_1,D_TG_1,E_CHOL_1,F_HDL_1,K_HCR_1)       
values (2,'2018-10-02','57','8.91','2.43','1.28','3.99','1.25','3.19')

insert into sample (Id,LAB_DATE,H_HBA1C_1)                              
values (2,'2018-10-03','8.6')                       

insert into sample (Id,LAB_DATE,J_GLUF_1)                               
values (2,'2018-10-04','7.8')

insert into sample (Id,LAB_DATE,A_CRE_1,B_GLUH_1,C_LDL_1,D_TG_1,E_CHOL_1,F_HDL_1,G_CRPH_1,H_HBA1C_1,K_HCR_1)
values (3,'2016-10-01','100','6.13','3.28','0.94','5.07','1.19','0.27','5.8','4.26')
```

Desired output:

```
ID|LAB_DATE|A_CRE_1|B_GLUH_1|C_LDL_1|Date_TG_1|D_TG_1|E_CHOL_1|F_HDL_1|G_CRPH_1|H_HBA1C_1|Date_GLU120_1|I_GLU120_1|J_GLUF_1|K_HCR_1
1|2017-11-21|74|6.4|2.04|2017-11-23|0.56|4.17|1.64|||6.1|2017-11-22|8.8|||2.54
2|02/10/2018|57|8.91|2.43||1.28|3.99|1.25||03/10/2018|8.6|||04/10/2018|7.8|3.19
3|01/10/2016|100|6.13|3.28||0.94|5.07|1.19|0.27||5.8|||||4.26
```

[image]

Comment: I don't see a clean way of doing this.  What would be wrong with just inserting a complete record in one go?

Comment: There are no duplicated values between the rows you want? You just want the value of each? You could do something like a group by ID getting the min lab_date and each of the values.

Comment: What will you do if there are two values for D_TG_1 values in sample for participant id 01? Take the latest one?

Comment: @TimBiegeleisen I think the record is inserting on date basis so `Stepahnie` you need an update in that case

Comment: Right now the solution I'm considering involves: select the id, date and single sample column, give it a rownunber (date ascending?), as a subquery. Repeat for all sample columns. Join all on id and rownumber. Nasty.

Comment: What would probably be better would be to write an sql that generates a bunch of MERGE statements as a one time op, then run them to collapse all these multiple records into one, then fix the program that creates them to be UPSERT style. Or write a trigger that turns the insert into an upsert if the program can't be fixed

Comment: @TimBiegeleisen: Quite impossible to insert about 1m records. Was wondering if i could get some help here.

Comment: @Ben: Nope. no duplicate values. all the lab test can be only done once for a participant (id)

Comment: @CaiusJard: All the lab test are only done once.

Comment: Hmm, I missed the fact that you want to include all the dates. Will I_GLU120_1 and  D_TG_1 always be in separate records, and the only ones to be in separate records, or was that just an example and there could be different tests on different days beyond that example?

Comment: @Ben: maybe i should update the dataset to a bigger one. because not I_GLU120_1 and D_TG_1 will always be separate records. eg. diabetic participant will take next day and the following due to some medical requirement whereas for healthy people they will take those test on the same day. thank you for your prompt response.

Comment: I'm not sure this can be done exactly how you've described your results, because the example has a date column specifically (and only) for the columns in the separate records, which means the columns returned would need to be variable for each Id. 
How do you intend to use the data? It might end up easier to instead handle multiple rows per id, or have a date per value regardless of whether it was in the original row or the newer ones?

Comment: @Ben: actually the raw data is way messier. so basically, each lab result initially has their own date. I use the following script to group them by date and visitid. SELECT ID,'LAB_DATE_1' = convert(date,Result_Date_Time,103), MAX(CASE WHEN TestID='16' THEN Results ELSE NULL END) [CRE_1], MAX(CASE WHEN TestID='17' THEN Results ELSE NULL END) [GLUH_1], ND) [HCR_1] FROM [tbBloodSample] GROUP BY convert(date,Result_Date_Time,103), ID
ORDER BY ID.

Comment: @Ben: i've used the max function to break it down to each row by date but now i am unable to break it down further into one row. each participant should only have 1 row because we are working with >1m data which will be joined to other medical data. hence one row data is required.

Comment: How do the dates factor into the joins?

Comment: This is a prime example of where the work already done to generate the "sample" data actually makes our job harder and probably performs far worse. Had this been apparent from the start I'd have recommended an entirely different solution

Comment: @Ben heya. we need to load these data with date into a model which we have created.

Comment: @CaiusJard: thank you for pointing it out but that was the initial requirement to group them by date and visitid to fit into the model we already have on hand. now that i am required to fit it all into one row which will be used for another analysis hence, i am asking this question.

Comment: You seem to be saying you've gone from A -> B and now need to go from B -> C. I'm proposing you go again from A -> C

Comment: @CaiusJard: as i previously mentioned that it is quite impossible to go back now as there are systems which are built on that structure. Hence, i am asking the question to find a work around. thank you for giving pointers.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Here's a solution (that cannot cope with multiple rows of the same id/sample type - you haven't said what to do with those)

```
select * from

  (select Id, LAB_DATE,A_CRE_1, B_GLUH_1,C_LDL_1,E_CHOL_1,F_HDL_1,H_HBA1C_1,K_HCR_1 from sample) s1
  INNER JOIN
  (select Id, LAB_DATE as glu120date, I_GLU120_1 from sample) s2
  ON s1.id = s2.id
  (select Id, LAB_DATE as dtgdate, D_TG_1 from sample) s3
  ON s1.id = s3.id
```

**Hopefully you get the idea with this pattern; if you have other sample types with their own dates, break them out of s1 and into their own subquery in a similar way (eg make an s4 for e_chol_1, s5  for k_hcr_1 etc).** Note that if any sample type is missing it will cause the whole row to disappear from the results. If this is not desired and you accept NULL for missing samples, use LEFT JOIN instead of INNER

If there will be multiple samples for patient 01 and you only want the latest, the pattern becomes:

```
select * from

  (select Id, LAB_DATE,A_CRE_1, B_GLUH_1,C_LDL_1,E_CHOL_1,F_HDL_1,H_HBA1C_1,K_HCR_1,
   row_number() over(partition by id order by lab_date desc) rn
   from sample) s1
  INNER JOIN
  (select Id, LAB_DATE as glu120date, I_GLU120_1,
   row_number() over(partition by id order by lab_date desc) rn
   from sample) s2
  ON s1.id = s2.id and s1.rn = s2.rn
WHERE
  s1.rn = 1
```

Note the addition of `row_number() over(partition by id order by lab_date desc) rn` - this establishes an incrementing counter in descending date order(latest record = 1, older = 2 ...) that restarts from 1 for every different id. We join on it too then say where rn = 1 to pick only the latest records for each sample type

Comment: this isn't comprehensive enough because it is not necessary that D_TG_1 is done on the next day. perhaps i should add a bigger sample space?

Comment: I didn't understand your comment. This code doesn't care when sampling is done. I can only work with the materials you give, I know only what you tell me. I did say "hopefully you can see the pattern" and I outlined how to expand it- add more subqueries for s4, s5.. make EVERY sampling it's own subquery if you need to. 10 samples, 10 days, 10 subqueries 10 joins.. Ypu can optimize things if you know that 5 tests will always be taken on the same day, but the othe r5 tests might happen on a mix (sometimes simultaneously, sometimes down to 1 a day for 5 days) then you need 6 subqueries

Comment: ..one subquery for the 5 that are one on th same day and another 5 that are done potentially individually

Comment: Ps; I'm not a fan of questions where the original source data isn't given; you have made efforts to transform he data already and have then asked us to write solutions on top of that. This can occasionally lead to poor interactions between what you've already done and what we provide, giving lower overall performance than if we'd seen and worked with the original data. Please avoid giving part baked data and presenting it as original source; either state the query you used to generate it or (better) state a representative sample of the source, possibly even as a http://db-fiddle.com or similar

Comment: Thank you for pointing it out. i have updated the sample dataset which i am working on. Thank you for trying to help.

Comment: thanks for sharing ur insights. i understood ur patter of joining the table to itself and selecting the desired columns as the test can only be keyed in once. i have expanded on this but i am still seeing what are the other options. thank you

Comment: Let us [continue this discussion in chat](https://chat.stackoverflow.com/rooms/187640/discussion-between-stephanie-and-caius-jard).

Answer (score 1):

As @Ben suggested, you can use group by id and take min for all column like below one.

```
DECLARE  @Sample as table (
  Id int,
  LAB_DATE date,
  A_CRE_1 varchar(100),
  B_GLUH_1 varchar(100),
  C_LDL_1 varchar(100),
  D_TG_1 varchar(100),
  E_CHOL_1 varchar(100),
  F_HDL_1 varchar(100),
  G_CRPH_1 varchar(100),
  H_HBA1C_1 varchar(100),
  I_GLU120_1 varchar(100),
  J_GLUF_1 varchar(100),
  K_HCR_1 varchar(100))

insert into @Sample(Id, LAB_DATE,A_CRE_1, 
B_GLUH_1,C_LDL_1,E_CHOL_1,F_HDL_1,H_HBA1C_1,K_HCR_1)
values (01,'2017-11-21','74','6.4','2.04','4.17','1.64','6.1','2.54')

insert into @Sample (Id, LAB_DATE, I_GLU120_1) 
values (01, '2017-11-22','8.8')

insert into @Sample (Id, LAB_DATE, D_TG_1) 
values (01, '2017-11-23','0.56')

SELECT s.Id
 , MIN(s.LAB_DATE) AS LAB_DATE
 , MIN(s.A_CRE_1) AS A_CRE_1
 , MIN(s.B_GLUH_1) AS B_GLUH_1
 , MIN(s.C_LDL_1) AS C_LDL_1
 , MIN(s.D_TG_1) AS D_TG_1
 , MIN(s.E_CHOL_1) AS E_CHOL_1
 , MIN(s.F_HDL_1) AS F_HDL_1
 , MIN(s.G_CRPH_1) AS G_CRPH_1
 , MIN(s.H_HBA1C_1) AS H_HBA1C_1
 , MIN(s.I_GLU120_1) AS I_GLU120_1
 , MIN(s.J_GLUF_1) AS J_GLUF_1
 , MIN(s.K_HCR_1) AS K_HCR_1
FROM @Sample AS s
GROUP BY s.Id
```

You can also check the SQL Server STUFF function. Can take help from the below link
https://www.mssqltips.com/sqlservertip/2914/rolling-up-multiple-rows-into-a-single-row-and-column-for-sql-server-data/

Comment: I downvoted this because it does not preserve each of the three dates, which the OP's output seems to have present.

Comment: That STUFF blog is really old, maybe suggest newer techniques like group_concat if the sqlserver is modern enough

Answer (score 0):

Following on from my comments about presenting the original data, here's what I think you should do  (taking the query you commented)

```
SELECT 
  ID, 
  MAX(CASE WHEN TestID='1' THEN Results END) [Test_1], 
  MAX(CASE WHEN TestID='2' THEN Results END) [Test_2], 
  MAX(CASE WHEN TestID='1' THEN Result_Date_Time END) Test12Date,
  MAX(CASE WHEN TestID='3' THEN Results END) [Test_3], 
  MAX(CASE WHEN TestID='3' THEN Result_Date_Time END) Test3Date

FROM [tbBloodSample] 
GROUP BY ID 
ORDER BY ID
```

Notes: If TestID is an int, don't use strings like '1' in your query, use ints. You don't need an ELSE NULL in a case- null is the default if the when didn't work out

Here is a query pattern. Test1 and 2 are always done on the same day, hence why I only pivot their date once. Test 3 might be done later, might be same, this means the dates in test12date and test3date might be same, might be different

Convert the strings to dates after you do the pivot, to reduce the number of conversions

Comment: thank you for pointing it out but this i am afraid is not possible as we have collected data and a system based on the requirements as well as sample space above. hence, i am seeking out help from this site if there is a clean way to convert multiple rows into one row.

Comment: This is the clean way to convert multiple rows into one - it's what a pivot operation does

Comment: thank you for sharing but this is what i did like 2 years ago with the first requirement. now i have the above dataset to work with.

Comment: Then use the other answer, extend the pattern to meet your needs using the information given in the body of the answer. We're here to help, but we don't give up time freely to write entire software systems for you.. There are of course, other sites where you can hire a freelancer to complete software to your exacting specification, but it's not what SO is for

Comment: yes yes. i've been testing out your other answer. it has been helpful. thank you! :)